# how to calculate the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{\ln n}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that:
$a_0=1$, $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{\sum_{I=1}^n a_i}$, how to calculate the limit:
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{\ln n}}$.

I want to calculate the limit by Stolz formula.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{\ln n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{\sqrt{\ln (n+1)}-\sqrt{\ln n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{{\sqrt{\ln (n+1)}+\sqrt{\ln n}}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i} $$

But I don't know what to do next. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you obtain the last equality?